# Issue running Symfony 3 on Apache

Tags: apache, symfony

I have Wamp64 running on my Windows 10 machine.

Localhost set up fine and I can see the Wamp64 home page at Localhost.

I've installed Symfony and followed the instructions as per their website.

I set up "project1" at C:\wamp64\www\project1, it has a public directory with an index.php file in it.

When I browse to http://localhost/project1/public/index.php I get an HTTP 404 error

[Error page...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5V8dy.png)

Should be getting the Symfony welcome page.

Any help gratefully received

Comment: check the error log

Comment: Seems symfony 4 to me (public directory, index.php). for symfony3 it should be project1/web/app_dev.php

Comment: Sorry yes absolutely right - Symfony 4 install..

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route with the path `/`

`routes.yaml`:

```
home:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::index' }
```

**OR**

Annotation:

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Matches / exactly
     *
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can also define these with XML and PHP. See [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html).

**IF** you're using Symfony 4 as suggested in the comments, the namespace is `App\Controller` and the localtion of your controller is `/src/Controller` instead of `/src/AppBundle/Controller`

Comment: Yes Symfony 4. I presume I need to install the composer annotations package as described in your link. Whereabouts does the routing.yaml file need to reside?

Comment: I've updated the routes.yaml file with: home:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: 'src\Controller\DefaultController::index' }. I now get InvalidArgumentException
in vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php (line 96)